# In batch file choice why if errorlevel need to be reversed

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch code using CHOICE command below.

```
:start
@echo off

echo How you feel right now?
echo A. Very nice
echo B. Good
echo C. OK
echo D. Could be better

choice /c:ABCD

if errorlevel == 4 goto cbb 
if errorlevel == 3 goto ok
if errorlevel == 2 goto g
if errorlevel == 1 goto vn

:vn
echo vn!
goto start

:g
echo g!
goto start

:ok
echo ok!
goto start

:cbb
echo cbb!
goto start
```

Now if I make the following change:

```
if errorlevel == 1 goto vn
if errorlevel == 2 goto g
if errorlevel == 3 goto ok
if errorlevel == 4 goto cbb
```

It echos `vn!` for *all* choices. Can you explain what went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the proper syntax is `if ErrorLevel 1 goto vn`, etc. (meaning *if ErrorLevel is **equal to or greater than** 1*; `ErrorLevel` is recognized as a special token here); the `==` in your syntax are nothing but token separators, just like spaces or tabs. You could also do `if %ErrorLevel% == 1 goto vn` (for a true *equal-to* comparison of the built-in variable `%ErrorLevel%` and 1), which requires the `==` as the comparison operator…

Answer (score 0):

I googled and came up with an explanation

> `if errorlevel == 1 goto vn` is interpreted `if errorlevel is 1 or greater goto vn`

so other errorlevels are not processed above.

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `if /?` or `help if` and read the output help. There is explained already on first page the correct syntax to evaluate the exit code of a command or executable assigned to the __dynamic__ variable (__not environment__ variable) `ERRORLEVEL`. That syntax exists since MS-DOS which supported already `IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command` more than 30 years ago. `if errorlevel == 1` is syntactically incorrect, but is automatically corrected to `if errorlevel 1` before the command is executed by `cmd.exe`.